# mysql_fetch_row() vs mysql_fetch_assoc() vs mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array, mysql_fetch_assoc, mysql_fetch_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object)

I want a function which can return fields in the current row of a resultset into an associative array and moves the result pointer to the next row.

Confused between

```
mysql_fetch_row()
mysql_fetch_assoc()
mysql_fetch_array()
```

Which one should I use? Any help would be appreciated.
 Thank you.

Comment: Why not read the documentation on php.net?

Comment: Why you don't search first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object?rq=1

Comment: There's also `mysql_fetch_object`, which naturally returns the row as an object, not an array.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> <sup>**Note**: The use of the `mysql_*` functions are considered *deprecated* and  you should instead use something that offers better security and more functionality, such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).</sup>

#### What is it?

You are looking for [`mysql_fetch_assoc`,](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) as the name implies it will return an associative array (with the column names as keys and the values as the row values).

---

#### What will the different functions return?

All of the mentioned functions will return an array, the differences between them is what values that are being used as keys in the returned object.

- **[`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)**

  This function will return a row where the values will come in the order as they are defined in the SQL query, and the keys will span from `0` to one less than the number of columns selected.
- **[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)**

  This function will return a row as an associative array where the column names will be the keys storing corresponding value.
- **[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)**

  This function will actually return an array with both the contents of `mysql_fetch_row`and `mysql_fetch_assoc` merged into one. It will both have *numeric* and *string* keys which will let you access your data in whatever way you'd find easiest.

  It is recommended to use either `_assoc` or `_row` though.

Comment: Note, all of these functions have nearly-identically-named counterparts in the mysqli API.  So you won't be losing anything or have much to relearn much if you switch.

Comment: According to the PHP site, both mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc will be deprecated, I don't know wether to laugh or cry.

Comment: As mentioned at the beginning of the answer, the `mysql_*` functions are officially deprecated. Using MySQLi, the counterparts for these functions are [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), and [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), respectively.

Answer (score 8):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` when you are manually referring to the fields.

`mysql_fetch_row` when you are using it as part of a `list($a,$b,$c...) = ...`

Never `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: This would be a more helpful answer if you mentioned why you would never use `mysql_fetch_array` (e.g., the performance impact, mixing associative and non-associative arrays, etc).

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_assoc()

Say your table has two columns id and name. You can use the following snippet -

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["name"];
}
```