# mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, database, arrays, mysqli, echo

Hey usually I use `mysqli_fetch_array` to display the content of my database in my CMS, but recently someone told me I should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and push the results into an array so that database only runs once instead of running the database for each record.

But I'm not really sure how to display my fields without showing them all, usually I would echo `$data['field_name']`, but what I've noticed with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is I can't just echo `$value['field_name']`, all I can do is echo `$value` and it displays all the results.

This is what I've done, hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help!

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM app_categories";

if($result = query($sql)){
    $list = array();

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($list, $data);
    }

    foreach($list as $i=>$row){      
        foreach($row as $column=>$value){
            echo $value;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480129/mysql-fetch-row-vs-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array

Comment: You have what you need in `$list`.  Do `foreach ($list as $row) { echo $row['field_name']; }`.  It is the unnecessary inner `foreach` you've got there which is tripping you up.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks, yeah thats what was really confusing me, that makes a lot more sense, thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

why you don't just

```
echo $row['field_name'];
```

Comment: That wasn't working because I had to many foreach, thanks again Michael!

Comment: yes,you had too many foreach. Michael answer is correct. I didn't notice he wrote a comment.