# Im new to php...plstell me what does the mysql_fetch_array($n1) does and what it loops

Tags: php

```
$sql="select name from exp";    
$n1 = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($n1)) {
   $msg[]=$row['name'];
}

echo json_encode($msg);
```

Please tell me what the `mysql_fetch_array($n1)` does and what it loops and what value will be assigned to `$msg` every time it loops.

Comment: If you're new to PHP, I suggest you get acquainted with the [documentation](http://au2.php.net/mysql_fetch_array). Its sole purpose is to answer these exact questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) fetch a row, each time you calling it; it depends on the number of rows returned from the query itself.

this line:

```
$msg[] = $row["name"];
```

takes the $row array, which is filled with the row's **fields** (`name` is one of them).
The fields are determined by query itself (`"select name.."`).

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($n1)) {
```

You are actually saying here: `as long there are rows to handle, give me the next one`.
The next one is stored in `$row` and you handle its fields.

You actually filling an array (`$msg`) with the field, so the resulting array will be like this:

```
$msg[0] = "some name";
$msg[1] = "another name";
...
```

Comment: could you explain  me the diff btwn mysql_fetch_array() and mysql_fetch_row()?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480129/mysql-fetch-row-vs-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array) you can find some nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

$n1 is a mysql resource.

mysql_fetch_array will talk to this resource and return you an array.

Here, as your request selects the "name" field of each line of the mysql table 'exp', the mysql_fetch_array() will return you the array : ["name"=>value] for each line of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not may be the best explanation but anyway:

```
$sql="select name from exp";    
$n1 = mysql_query($sql);
//$n1 returns the whole result set from your query, this means it contains 
//all the values of 'name' from your table 'exp'

//mysql_fetch_array will retrieve each 'name' from the result set $n1
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($n1)) {
//$msg is an array, writing [] makes it auto-increment its index
//depending on the order of your records, the first 'name' returned from your 
//table will be assigned to $msg and the second time it loops, the second 'name' 
//will be assigned and so on.
   $msg[]=$row['name'];
//so this will be saved as $msg[0] = 'first name', $msg[1] = 'second name'
//and so on till the end of records
}

echo json_encode($msg);
```

Comment: the second time it loops,will it be reassigned or will it push the element into $msg..

Comment: @NithishReddyJ It will not be reassigned because of the `[]`, it auto-increments to the next array index. Yes, it will push it into `$msg`.