# Simple PHP rest json duplicates data fields

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm iOS developer and for finishing prototype I need simple php code which could return data from particular table as JSON. Here is a code I developed:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database) or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "select * from Events" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connection));
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    $events = array();

    while ($event = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {       

        $events[] = $event; 
    }

    echo json_encode($events);

    $result->free();
    $connection->close();
?>
```

The problem is that it duplicates data fields. Here is a result I receive:

```
[
   {
      "0":"1",
      "id":"1",
      "1":"Some title",
      "title":"Some title"
   }
]
```

In database I have one record only.

How to solve the following problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use associative array, will definately work...!

```
while ($event = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $events[] = $event; 
}
```

And You used **header('Content-Type: application/json');** - its good, but also try by
removing it as well.

Comment: Thanks. It works well. Since I use object oriented style I updated code in next way: (see edited topic)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

> "Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both"
>
> resulttype parameter: This optional parameter is a constant indicating
> what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The
> possible values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC,
> MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH.

It would appear you are using BOTH. Switch to ASSOC or NUM. ASSOC is usually easier.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

For JSON you would proably want to do:

`while ($event = mysqli_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {`

Answer (score 0):

you can see this [OT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480129/mysql-fetch-row-vs-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array) then you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to fix the error, since the one you are using right now returns also an array, that is why you are getting duplicated data.