# PHP MYSQL if field equals checked echo

Tags: php, mysql, session, if-statement, echo

Each user in the databased is assigned a level, their is a table for levels and each level has permissions eg "view-clients" at login the user's level is made into $_SESSION['level'] i need to make an if statement that will echo code if the user's level "view-clients" is "checked".

This is the code is have but it wont echo it even when it is checked.

```
<?php
$level = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['level']);
include("include/config.php");
$con=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uname,$db_pwd,$db_name);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$query = "SELECT * FROM levels WHERE name='$level'";

            $result=mysql_query($query);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $a1=$rows['0'];
                $a2=$rows['1'];
                $a3=$rows['2'];
                $a4=$rows['3'];
                $a5=$rows['4'];
                $a6=$rows['5'];
                $a7=$rows['6'];
                $a8=$rows['7'];


if ($a5=="checked") { 

echo "Clients"; 

     }

 }

?>
```

I have tried a few things such as not using a variable as the session. 
I am thankful for any help.

Comment: So `name` is unique in `levels`? Did you try `var_dump($row[5]);` inside the loop to see if you're getting anything at all?

Comment: I guess this is where im going wrong, its not outputting anything. I have triple checked everything and it is spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to start session.

try that

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $level = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['level']);
  ....
```

your query will not find and result while  `$level` is not defined.

also chanage this

```
 mysql_fetch_array
```

to

```
mysql_fetch_row
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480129/mysql-fetch-row-vs-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array) the difference betwen fetch row and fetch array and fetch assoc

Comment: Its not displaying any

Comment: try make this in top of page `ini_set('display_errors',1);` or in your php.ini locate and do this `display_errors = on`

Comment: if nothing happen , then you have to check if you are really submitting  having value for `$_SESSION['level']` , if not , then check that you made session_start() also in the file you defining this variable.

Comment: added, still not displaying any, it used to display errors but then i found what was wrong and fixed them.

Comment: as i said check the other file where you defining session['level'] and check if you have session_start().

Comment: yeah its defined in my login.php file, and it has session_start() in it.

Comment: last suggest , you sure that you checking for `$a5` ?

Comment: The code is in my sidebar.php (show extra nav menu if has permissions) and is included in the other pages, could this be affecting it?