# SQL Query only fetching the first word from a string column

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
 include('common/connect.class.php');
include('common/admin.class.php');
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$con2 = new connection(); 
$con = $con2->connect();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM xam_category"; //Select Query
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());;

echo "<table align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Category name</th>
<th>Category Description</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
{
echo "<form action=user_book.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=10 readonly='true' name=usrname value=" .      $record['category_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=15 readonly='true' name=usrmail value=" . $record['category_desc'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=DELETE" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=UPDATE" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
} 
mysql_close($con);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

My SELECT query and data fetching is working fine. But, while i echo the fetched data, it only shows the first word "Computer" where it's actual value is "Computer Science".

The data stored in database viewed through PhpMyAdmin seems ok. But,

[image: Data in the Database]

The data shown in the .php page is different and not ok.

[image: Data in the php page]

I'm Stuck.
How to display the right string from MySQL database on the PHP page?

Note: I'm using html inside echo to loop & display all data. Sorry, I have to use mysql() functions could'nt do msqli(). I also viewed other same type questions in StackOveflow. But, Couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a value with a space in it, you must enclose that value within quotes in your HTML. Try with

```
echo "<td><input type=text size=10 readonly='true' name='usrname' value='".$record['category_name']."'</td>";
```

Comment: I can only accept it after 3 minutes. Don't you know? hoping +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **mysql_fetch_assoc** instead of **mysql_fetch_array** if you would like to access to variable like `$record['category_name']`.

Please read this article: [mysql_fetch_row() vs mysql_fetch_assoc() vs mysql_fetch_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480129/mysql-fetch-row-vs-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array)