# how to json encode format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, encode

i'm trying to get some json print. I have a simple format but i didn't figure it out.

But my result is like that. `{"datas":{"title":"table"}}`

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
    $array = array("table"=>$check["title"]);
    $result=json_encode(array('datas' => $array));
    echo($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
```

I need this is my format `{"datas":[{"0":"table","title":"table"}]}`

I guess i miss something.

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead, need a mysqli version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480129/mysql-fetch-row-vs-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array so it can be closed. Same applies anyway.

Comment: $array[] = $check; it works but i need to put some other data manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
    $array = array("table"=>$check["title"]);
    $result=json_encode(array('datas' => $array));
    echo($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
```