# mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

Whats different between `mysql_fetch_array` and `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

I did a testing from my database.

$a echo out first row twice, I use count() to check and it print out double from my column
$b echo out second row once.

Anyone can tell me why?

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);

$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

$a=implode(mysql_fetch_array($SQL));
$b=implode(mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL));


echo $a . "<HR/>";
echo $b;
```

Comment: Start by reading the manual: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc, http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: you can get complete explanation just if you google it..show some research effort before posting a question here

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array, mysql\_fetch\_assoc, mysql\_fetch\_object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object)

Answer (score 3):

1. [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) — Fetch a result row as an associative array
2. [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns essentially two arrays, one with a numeric index and one with an associative based key index. Thus using `mysql_fetch_array()` without specifying which method you want (either `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_ASSOC`) always returns a double array, which is considerably more inefficient as compared to `mysql_fetch_row()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.