# Unable to retrieve data from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Firstly, I am new to php.  I am also new to MySQL, so be gentle with me.  Secondly, I know mysql_* is depreciated and this will be fixed at a later point once I understand more.

So I have the following code:

```
        if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
            $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

            $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

            if($match > 0){
                $user=$search['forename'] .' '.$search['surname'];
                $_SESSION['username']=$user;
                $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks, '.$user.'!';
            }else{
                $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';
            }
        }
```

Quite simply, I am checking that the email and password match(I know it's not a hashed password...again, not an issue as it's a test).  If they do, and the account has been activated, then I want to return the users first and last name (forename/surname in the users table) and store them in a session variable.  If that variable isset, I want to use this information to confirm that the user has logged in(and so have access to certain pages).  However, this test doesn't return the user name, instead outputting:

> Login Complete! Thanks, !

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: mysql_num_rows is now deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: you need mysql_fetch_array: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
    $user=$row['forename'] .' '.$row['surname'];  
}

Comment: What happens when you run this? Do you get a sql connection error? or nothing at all?

Comment: Please read post.  I know it's depreceated(I actually state this).  Also, I list the output of the script near the bottom of the post.

Comment: **First, do not use mysql_* please. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

You can use mysqli_query() or PDO::query().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the the value return by `mysql_query` is resource so you need to fetch the result row as an associative array.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) 
{
    $user=$row['forename'] .' '.$row['surname'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$user;
}
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: This works perfectly.  I removed the loop as it should only be 1 record max (email is the primary key).  Now I just need to get to work on checking that the session works well.  I've been meaning to read up on stopping injections more, so I will definitely check the link, thank you!

Comment: How does this differ from mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: [mysql_fetch_array, mysql_fetch_assoc, mysql_fetch_object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `$row = mysql_fetch_array($search);`

And then

```
$user=$row['forename'] .' '.$row['surname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace your code
/**************************Your Code***********/
        if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
            $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

```
        $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

        if($match > 0){
            $user=$search['forename'] .' '.$search['surname'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$user;
            $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks, '.$user.'!';
        }else{
            $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';
        }
    }
```

To

/**************************MY Code***********/

```
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

        if($match > 0){
            $search = mysql_fetch_array($search); 
            $user=$search['forename'] .' '.$search['surname'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$user;
            $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks, '.$user.'!';
        }else{
            $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not give example with deprecated function like mysql_*.