# Not displaying searched usernames?

Tags: php

My code should print out all the users' usernames it finds, but it does not, merely prints 'User Found:' once. Please help me fix it; this is my code, thanks!

```
<?php
echo'
<form method="post">
<input name="newSearch" id="newSearch" class="inputs" placeholder="Search for a user...">
<input type="submit" id="submit_search" name="submit_search" class="button" value="Search">
</form>';
if ($_POST['submit_search']) {
$search = $_POST['newSearch'];
$getUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username  LIKE '%$search%'");
while($id=mysql_fetch_assoc($getUser)){
$gU = mysql_fetch_object($getUser);
echo "User Found: ", $gU->Username, "<br />";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `addslashes()`, using vintage code?

Comment: @DavidHoude Function names are case insensitive in PHP so it is valid

Comment: Did not know either. Removed it, now it only shows some of the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of the below,

```
while($id=mysql_fetch_assoc($getUser)){
echo "User Found: ". $id["Username"]. "<br />";
}
```

OR,

```
while($gU = mysql_fetch_object($getUser)){
echo "User Found: ". $gU->Username . "<br />";
}
```

Anyone of the above code helps you to survive your situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "User Found: " . $gU->Username . "<br />"
```

Should Be:

```
echo "User Found: " . $id["Username"] . "<br />"
```

EDIT:

You should choose to work with arrays or objects, please view: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object` for the differences. I would also advise you to move away from depreciated code.

**Work with Object:**

```
while($id=mysql_fetch_object($getUser)){
    echo "User Found: " . $id->Username . "<br />";
}
```

**Work with Array:**

```
while($id=mysql_fetch_assoc($getUser)){
    echo "User Found: " . $id["username"] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That made it work 0%, it was working with half the names with $gU->Username

Comment: @Sam my apologizes for that, I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're going through two records with each iteration of the loop. `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `mysql_fetch_object` each grab a record and increment the pointer into the record set. You almost certainly want.

You almost certainly want:

```
while($gU=mysql_fetch_object($getUser)){
   echo "User Found: " . $gU->Username . "<br />";
}
```

or

```
while($gU=mysql_fetch_assocc($getUser)){
   echo "User Found: " . $gU["Username"] . "<br />";
}
```