# Double Selecting Data From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hey so i am trying to grab data from mysql database and i am getting double the data in my table when i grab the data from mysql?

Here is the code i am using to make the graph.

```
$query = "SELECT id,username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    foreach($row as $id => $val)
    {
        echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only single loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>";
}
```

instead of double loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    foreach($row as $id => $val)
    {
        echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you feeling stupid since it was a quick easy fix haha.

Answer (score 1):

Use onli sing loop...while loop or foreach...you are using both the loops e.g foreach inside while..Use that

```
$query = "SELECT id,username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

        echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "mysql_fetch_array" instead of "mysql_fetch_assoc":

```
$query = "SELECT id,username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 
    "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between the two do you know?

Comment: @Terrii Check the difference from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object)

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc(): Fetch a result row as an associative array

Comment: mysql_fetch_array(): Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array and also it fetches by both associative & numeric array.