# PHP SQL: select data from 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables

**Tbl A** Cols :
*id nama kdwil*

**Tbl B** Cols :
*id nama kdwil*

Want show all data from that tables which `kdwil` is somevalue

So, I did

```
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM a, b where a.kdwil=b.kdwil and a.kdwil='$kdwil'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
        echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value='".$row2['nama']."'>".$row2['nama']."</label>";
```

But returned no results.

Comment: You should be using PDO / MySQLi, mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM a, b where a.kdwil=b.kdwil and a.kdwil='$kdwil'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){ 
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value='".$row2['nama']."'>".$row2['nama']."</label>";
```

Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but result printed why just from tbl B? can you explain this?thanks

Comment: Check these post.
[mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object)