# Retrieve database entry with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Have the following PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT status FROM updates";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo '<div class="statusRow">' . "Status: " . $row['status'] . '</div>';
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The above is not returning the desired 'status' input, just blank. Not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: basic error checking and display.

Comment: @KevinP the output is "Status: "

Comment: Change $row['status'] to $row[0]

Comment: @KevinP 100% sure. I've quadruple checked. I add `print_r($row['status'])` inside the while loop and now "Status: 1" is returned. Not sure what the 1 is referring to though?

Comment: @KevinP changing to $row[0] seems to have done the trick. What exactly does the 0 mean?

Comment: ok. i mistakenly used mysqli_fetch_row instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array, mysql\_fetch\_assoc, mysql\_fetch\_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536813/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you using mysqli_fetch_row, it returns numeric array.
You need to switch to mysqli_fetch_assoc.
Then you will be able to access via string $row['status']

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Change `$row['status']` to `$row[0]` or use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`